# setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch); stretches table out of viewport

Tags: qt

I'm trying to use Qt's built-in functionality for table stretch-fitting (`table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);`) but the table is stretched out of the viewport.

I remember seeing somewhere that there might not be a solution and I'd have to do some subclassing since the purpose of a scroll area is to allow this going-out-of-bounds in the first place, but anyway:

What I'm aiming for:

[image]

What I'm getting:

[image]

What's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: And what is your `minimumSectionSize` ? Maybe it's too much.

Comment: @Tomas That was exactly it, Thank you very much! (I'll accept this if you post it as an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `QHeaderView::minimumSectionSize()`. Header sections can't shrink below this size.